# PHP: Why are my variables not available after I included them with a request statement?

Tags: php, variables, scope, request

I am learning Php at Coursera and right now we are supposed to do a simple CRUD (create, read, update, delete) web application.

For my login program I "outsourced" all error messages to a separate file called "errors.php":

```
<?php
$errors = array(
"email" => "Email must have an at-sign (@)",
"login" => "Email and password are required",
"pass"  =>  "Incorrect password");
?>
```

And now I wanted to include (request) it within my login routine. As you see I included/requested it twice. From what I understand the first request should be enough for the errors-variable to be available within the whole login script. It should have a global scope. Correct?

But after quite some debugging I found out that I have to request it within the function "returnOnerror" to be available within this function call.

Aren't global variables accessible within a function? The other way round, I would understand that...

```
<?php
session_start();

require("errors.php");

function returnOnerror($whaterror){
  require("errors.php");
  $_SESSION["error"] = $errors[$whaterror];
  header('location: login.php');
exit();
}

if ((isset($_POST['email'])) && (isset($_POST['pass']))){
  $salt = 'XyZzy12*_';
  $stored_hash = '1a52e17fa899cf40fb04cfc42e6352f1'; //(salted hash + php123)
  $passhash = hash('md5', $salt.$_POST['pass']);

if ((strlen($_POST['email']<1)) && (strlen($_POST['pass'])<1)) {
  returnOnerror("login");
}

if ((substr_count($_POST['email'], '@'))<1){
  returnOnerror('email');
}

if ($passhash==$stored_hash){
  $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['email'];
  $_SESSION['login'] = "logged in";
  header('location: index.php');
exit();
}
else {
  returnOnerror("pass");
}
}
?>
```

Btw, I searched here on Stackexchange and on the web to find an explanation but wasn't able. Thus I turned over here as the last chance. Thanks.

Comment: *"Aren't global variables accessible within a function?"* - [nope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Thanks. Thus unless I explicitly declare it a global I have to request variables exactly where they are needed...

Comment: Just replace `require("errors.php");` in your function with `global $errors;` - since you are always declaring `$errors` before the function, it should be safe